# Creating a simple Table in WPF?

Tags: wpf, charts, components

I was wondering if there is a way (any components/controls) that allow me to draw a simple Microsoft Word style table in my application window. Something like this:

[image: Sample Table]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It depends on how you want to use it. Either use one of the `ItemsControl` (like `DataGrid`, `ListView` etc), do it directly with a `Grid` panel (as recommended by the other answers) or use a `FlowDocument`

`FlowDocument` allows you to specify Tables, Rows and Columns. You can also select several cells at once for Copy/Paste etc.

[image]

```
<FlowDocumentReader UseLayoutRounding="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <FlowDocumentReader.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TableCell">
            <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </FlowDocumentReader.Resources>
    <FlowDocument>
        <Table CellSpacing="0">
            <Table.Columns>
                <TableColumn/>
                <TableColumn/>
                <TableColumn/>
                <TableColumn/>
            </Table.Columns>
            <TableRowGroup>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableCell BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                        <Paragraph FontWeight="Bold">Category</Paragraph>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,1,1,1">
                        <Paragraph FontWeight="Bold">A</Paragraph>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,1,1,1">
                        <Paragraph FontWeight="Bold">B</Paragraph>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,1,1,1">
                        <Paragraph FontWeight="Bold">C</Paragraph>
                    </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableCell BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1">
                        <Paragraph FontWeight="Bold">Subscription</Paragraph>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                        <Paragraph>Monthly</Paragraph>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                        <Paragraph>Yearly</Paragraph>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                        <Paragraph>Monthly</Paragraph>
                    </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableCell BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" TextAlignment="Center">
                        <Paragraph FontWeight="Bold">Price</Paragraph>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                        <Paragraph>$120.00</Paragraph>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                        <Paragraph>$1000.00</Paragraph>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                        <Paragraph>$130.00</Paragraph>
                    </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
            </TableRowGroup>
        </Table>
    </FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentReader>
```

This page is full of usefull examples about this: [FlowDocument with Table](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0470__Windows-Presentation-Foundation/FlowDocumentwithTable.htm)

Comment: +1 I was unaware of `FlowDocument` I finished a medium sized WPF app about 18 months ago, and have done nothing with it since. My Xaml-Fu has grown quite rusty :(

Comment: For some odd reason, when I create a table, I get a search field and different views for my table. How can I remove all that information and just include the table without the extra fancy features?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend starting with [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/) DataGrid control.

Here is an ok tutorial on how to use it:
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-the-wpf-toolkit-datagrid