# How can I create a Table using FlowDocumentReader and not have the reader properties attached?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Apparently, creating a simple table in WPF isn't as easy as 123.. yet.

The only resources I can find online redirect me to FlowDocumentReader.

I tried this example from a previous StackOverflow question: [Creating a simple Table in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385163/creating-a-simple-table-in-wpf/7385388#comment35343116_7385388)

in my WPF application and it seems like, it doesn't only create a table... It creates a table with a bunch of unnecessary items attached at the bottom such as a search function and different page views (one page, two page, etc..). I don't want the reader function, I just want to create a basic nice looking table. That is, a table that contains rows and columns. How can I create a table in WPF?

I'm very new to WPF, so I hope this is not too naive of a question.

**UPDATE:**

How I can make a basic table using FlowDocumentReader without the extra features?

Comment: If you want to make it look like the `kendo ui` you provided. Why not use `DataGrid`?

Comment: Ohhh that's exactly what I'm looking for! I didn't know of DataGrid. Every time I tried to look up Grids in documentation, I just got the wpf basic grid and that wasn't what I was looking for. Thank you! But I guess to make the question more interesting, let's see how I can make a basic table using FlowDocumentReader without the extra features? I will edit the question.

Comment: `FlowDocument` is intended to be used for `Document`, not UIs. You're looking for a `DataGrid`.

Comment: @KalaJ Answered your future question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the built in features included in the control, edit the `FlowDocumentReader` template. If you have `Expression Blend` then you can just drop the control and right click on it and say edit template so it'll generate the existing template for it then you can modify it from there.

If you want to use more than one states or your template you could make 2 different templates and assign to the reader.

If you want to remove the zoom toobar, you can redefine the FlowDocumentReader's ControlTemplate.

If you want to remove the zoom functionality from the FlowDocumentReader, the following snippet should do the trick:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type FlowDocumentReader}">
  <Setter Property="MinZoom" Value="100"/>
  <Setter Property="MaxZoom" Value="100"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: Btw, I am wondering can I add rows using XAML or would I have to add rows using C# in my viewmodel? (For DataGrid)

Comment: `C#` you can use XAML for defining how it would look like. More of this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee344869(v=vs.110).aspx